# Point in Time recovery for PostgreSQL running on google cloud

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

As titled, Google cloud supports point-in-time recovery for MySQL. GC also supports PostgreSQL. But does GC support Point in time recovery for PostgreSQL ? I can't see any documentation that it does - and it appears that one needs host OS console access in order to do this. Can anyone confirm / deny this either way ?

Answer (score 3):

Point-in-time recovery (PITR) is no yet available with Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL.

You can check it here [[PostgreSQL features](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/features#features_not_yet_available)].

Comment: In addition to that, feel free to poke/vote feature request in our issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78448400